# Using python-memcached and the Pyramid Framework Pserve Server

Tags: python, memcached, pyramid

My web application uses the Pyramid framework, and runs on a Debian Linux system. I'm adding `python-memcached` to the application but cannot get the objects to be stored and retrieved. I get a null value when I retrieve a object from memcached using the key I used to set it with. The testing/debugging server I am using is the Pyramid Framework `pserve` server.

```
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:6543'], debug=0)
mc.set('key1', 'value1', 10)
val = mc.get('key1')
```

The val is equal to  'null'.

The command I use to run the application is:

```
$ pserve development.ini --reload
```

Comment: Please add more detail to the question, what avenues you've tried, some code samples, memcached configuration and the like.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your memcache server is being run on port 6543 -- assuming you're using the default pyramid config file, your development server is running on port 6543, your memcache server is probably on port 11211. Try running the memcache server and then set

`mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)`